# "possessive" can't be in front of the word "weight"?

Tags: word-usage

**I lost my weight vs I lost weight.**

I heard that the former sentence is wrong, because "possessive" can't be in front of the word "weight". 
If so, why?

Comment: If you're referring to the heavy items one lifts in order to increase muscle and reduce body fat, then _I lost my weight_ is fine.  (It would be more obvious if you said _I lost my 5lb. weight, but I still have my 10lb. weight._)  If, however, you want to indicate that you have reduced your body's weight, (and assuming you've not suddenly become weightless,) you'll use weight as a mass noun and say that you've lost [some] weight.

Comment: You _could_ say _I've **reduced** my weight_ because you're referring to your weight as a whole.  To say _I've **lost** my weight_, on the other hand, means you've lost all your weight -- you've somehow become weightless.

Comment: If you went weightless then you temporarily lost your weight. No problem with the possessive. The weight of an object -> the object's weight. Likewise, an object that is a person. You can also lose *some* of your weight, in which case you are not weightless.

Answer (score 1):

'Weight' is a normal noun (usually a mass noun, except when it refers to individual objects for use on a balance or in a gym), and it can take possessives like any other noun.

However there are two specific phrases (you might almost call them "compound verbs") *lose weight* and *gain weight*. There may be one or two other verbs that pattern this way, but I can't think of any. Certainly there is no "keep weight" - you would say "He kept his weight" (though it's an unlikely thing to say, when people are mostly concerned with getting their weight down!).

Answer (score 0):

The possessive is acceptable depending on the circumstance.  Imagine a group of people who had successfully completed a weight-loss challenge.  The discussion might include descriptions of how each person lost his or her weight.  In that case, the possessive is used to distinguish one person's method of weight loss from another's.

Comment: No, it's simpler than that. We use a determiner (such as a possessive) except in the fixed expressions "lose weight" and "gain weight".